# Python request used to download the .csv file has been blocked, however, I could manually click it to download from the web

Tags: python, download, request, blocked

This is my code:

```
              import requests
              import time
              from datetime import timedelta, date

              uls = []
              ul_endpoint = 'https://marketplace.spp.org/file- 
              api/download/da-binding-constraints?path='

              def daterange(start_date, end_date):
                  for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
                      yield start_date + timedelta(n)

              start_date = date(2018, 1, 1)
              end_date = date(2018, 3, 9) 

              for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
                  y = single_date.strftime('%Y')    
                  m = single_date.strftime('%m') 
                  ymd = single_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')  
                  designator1 = 'DA'
                  designator2 = 'BC'
                  ul_head = ['']+[y]+[m]+['By_Day']+['']
                  fn = [designator1]+[designator2]+[ymd+'0100.csv']
                  ul_parm = '%2F'.join(ul_head)
                  fn = '-'.join(fn)
                  ul = ul_endpoint+ul_parm+fn
                  uls.append({'fn': fn, 'ul': ul})  

              import warnings
              warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

              t = time.time()
              for item in uls:
                  t0 = time.time()
                  fn = item['fn']
                  ul = item['ul']
                  r = requests.get(ul, verify=False)
                  data = r.text
                  with open('data' + '/'+fn, "w") as fw:
                  fw.write(data)`
                  print('%s completed, time elapsed: %.2f' % (fn, time.time
                  ()-t0))     
                  print('%d files downloaded, total time elapsed: %.2f' % 
                  (len(uls), time.time()-t))
```

It works!!
However, if I run it more than several times, like five or six, it will block the request, like:[image]

I believe my method is not good. Someone could shown me better methods?

Comment: You probably need to either slow down your requests (`sleep`) between each one, or perhaps the server is handing back a session cookie you need to keep and re-use?

Comment: Consider reading [this question and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze the response HTTP code (`r.status_code`) to understand why the destination site does what it does. It is likely that by repeatedly querying it without delay you are exceeding their request rate limit (HTTP code 429).

Read the site's terms of service and follow them to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, when I add " print(r.status_code)", it shown "200". How do I interpret such number?

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I still did not get it. Could you recommend some youtube video, I could learned from it?